# Rails Association Convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

There are three models that are relevant to this question `Transaction` `Bid` and `Auction`. An auction is created and then bids are created in that auction obviously. A transaction is created once the buyer has chosen a bid and checked out, so after auction and bid.

The transaction has an association to the Auction and the Bid, and contains a lot of information regarding the transaction (ie. shipping info, tax, price breakdown by line item). Right now I've got

Transaction

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :auction
    has_one :bid
```

Bid

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tx, class_name: "Transaction", foreign_key: "transaction_id"
```

Auction

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tx, class_name: "Transaction", foreign_key: "transaction_id"
```

Should my `belongs_to` and `has_one` be switched? If so how?
Right now my `Bid` and `Auction` have a `transaction_id`. And my `Transaction` has an `auction_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your associations are backwards.

If an Auction is created first, and then Bids are created for an auction, then your `Bid` needs an `auction_id` foreign key.

If a Transaction is created *after* a series of bids happen for an auction, your `Transaction` should have a foreign key `bid_id`, and does not need an `auction_id` foreign key as there is already an implicit link through the `bid`.

Your Rails associations would then be setup thusly:

```
class Auction
  has_many :bids
end

class Bid
  belongs_to :auction
end

class Transaction
  belongs_to :bid
  has_one :auction, through: :bid
end
```

Comment: There doesn't need to be a `has_one :transaction` in the Bid model?

Comment: @gemart Only if you need to be able to go from a `Bid` to its (optional) `Transaction`. If you do, then you can add a `has_one :transaction`, but if you never need to look up the Transaction for a given bid, then the `has_one` is not necessary. Associations do not have to be declared on both sides unless you intend to use it on both sides.

Comment: I need to be able to call `@bid.tx` but I can't @meagar

Comment: @gemart then yes, you need a `has_one` in `Bid`.

Comment: and for `@auction.tx` to be available?